# Proving that when $\nu(x) = \nu(y)$  in the Gaussian integers they are associates

Tags: abstract-algebra

I think I'm missing something here but my lecture notes just seem to state that 'clearly' for $x$ and $y$ in the Gaussian integers (elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, a Euclidean domain), if  $\nu(x) = \nu(y)$ then clearly $x$ and $y$ are associates. Am I missing something here or is this obvious?

Comment: What is $\nu$? Is it the square of the complex absolute value, as Brian assumed?

Comment: @Hurkyl: Good point: I too assumed $\nu$ was the norm of a Gaussian integer.  But what else could it be?

Comment: So let us wait until the OP dignifies us with an explanation about his/her notation: what is $\,\nu\,$, anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Either I’m misunderstanding something, or the statement is false.

Let $x=2+i$. The units of $\Bbb Z[i]$ are $1,-1,i$, and $-i$, so the associates of $x$ are $x$, $-2-i$, $-1+2i$, and $1-2i$. Now let $y=1+2i$; $y$ is not an associate of $x$, but $\nu(y)=5=\nu(x)$.

An even better example: $\nu(8+i)=65=\nu(7+4i)$.